# same line height for <dd> <dt> attributes / whitespaces in definition lists

Tags: css, dynamic, line-breaks, lines

I can't find a solution for this:

Within my Application the table is defined with `<dd>` and `<dt>` within `<dl>`. 
As my contents in Document Title are too long to fit in one row there is the possibility to say "`whitespace: no-wrap`" as well as "`white-space: normal`" - while the abbreviation of the label with "…" is the thing i want to avoid as the user needs the whole title to understand. So the lable needs to be in two lines. That's not the problem, but how can i tell the following  attribute to have the same line-height as the  attribute above?

I copied the Code with the given css attributes in this Pen: (sorry for crappy code, the development system is giving a lot of stuff here)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOKveK

Giving more space to the whole table is not possible as there is no more width to give within the application.

What could be the best solution to have a dynamic css without defining always 2 lines, fixed line-height for the whole definition list or other hard fixes?

Thanks for answering & reading

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your CSS, in addition to whatever other styling you want for you list:

```
dt, dd { display: block; float: left; }
dt { clear: both; }
```